# Shutdownhook - Log not printed in console/File @Predestroy method

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, shutdown-hook, spring-logback

Hav spring boot application, While invoking Shutdown hook @Predestroy method is called and application shutdown happens. 
But Logs are not printed in both console and file, sys out line after the log is printed.
It seems, Looger console shutdown before the application/process shutodwn.

Suggest some work around to resolve the issue.

Shutdown script:

SET /P PID_FROM_FILE= < application.pid
 taskkill /pid %PID_FROM_FILE% /f

Gracefulshutdown hook class:

```
@Component
public class GracefulShutdownHook {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(GracefulShutdownHook.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inboundChannel")
MessageChannel inboundChannel;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("pollingExecutor")
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pollingExecutor;

@PreDestroy 
public void onDestroy() throws Exception {

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Application shutdown Initiated"); // this log is not printed
    System.out.println(""Application shutdown Initiated""); // Sys out is printed

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Application shutdown Processing"); // this log is not printed

    inboundChannel.send(new  GenericMessage<String>"@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop()"));

    pollingExecutor.shutdown();

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Application shutdown succesfully"); // not printed
}

 @Bean
 public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator() {
 return () -> 0;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have created a race condition between logging and shutdown; that is, shutdown is taking place before logging can complete. Try adding a short sleep at the end of your @PreDestroy method and see it that makes a difference.

Comment: Adding sleep did not help. Any suggestion ?